# How to use -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option?

Tags: c, xlc

I am getting warnings about duplicate symbols during my C compile on AIX 6.1 and it says:

ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.

I have looked up on Google how to use these but no clear answer yet, can someone please tell me what I need to do in order to use -bloadmap or -bnoquiet?

Thanks for the help ;-)

Lynton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either:

```
xlc -bloadmap:map.file you other paramaters ...
```

which will generate a `map.file` which lists where the duplicate symbols come from.

Or:

```
xlc -bnoquiet you other paramaters ...
```

which will list the same information to `stdout`.

Example duplicate information:

```
 Symbol                    Source-File(Object) OR Import-File{Shared-object}
 ------------------------- -------------------------------------------------
 ...
 .main                     t.c(t2.o)
    ** Duplicate **        t.c(t1.o)
```

which tells me I have a `main` function both in `t1.o`  and `t2.o`.